# Use regex recursively taking indentation level into account

Tags: regex, recursion, indentation

I am trying to parse a custom input file for a simulation code I am writting. It consist of nested "objects" with properties, values (see the link).

Here is [an example file and the regex I am using currently](https://regex101.com/r/G11Ouz/1).

```
([^:#\n]*):?([^#\n]*)#?.*\n
```

It is made such that each match is a line, with two capture group, one for the property and one for its value. It also excludes "#" and ":" from the character set, as they correspond to a comment delimiter and a property:value delimiter respectively.

How can I modify my regex so as to match the structure recursively? That is if line n+1 has an identation level higher than line n, it should be matched as a subgroup of line n's match.

I am working on Octave, which uses PCRE regex format.

Comment: Are you producing the file that you want to parse, Or are you receiving it as it is in the example?

Comment: I produce it, but the end users will have to modify it with their own parameters, so I want to keep it as simple and human readable as possible.

Comment: As PCRE doesn't support capture stacks, all you'd get with this is one giant match for the "case" label. You'd then have to split the value and match it again against the same regex. I think it'd be best for you to write a simple parser manually and be done with it, for such a format it should be *really* simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked if you have control over the data format because as it is, the data is very easy to parse with YAML instead of regex.

The only problem is that the object is not well formed:

1) Take the `regions` object for example, it has many attributes called `layer` all of them. I think your intention is to build a list of `layer`s instead of a lot of properties with the same name.

2) Consider now each `layer` property that has a corresponding value. Following each `layer` are orphan attributes that I presume belong to each layer.

With these ideas in mind. If you form your object following YAML rules, it would be a breeze to parse it.

I know that you are working in Octave, but consider the modifications I made to your data, and how easy it is to parse it, in this case with python.

**DATA AS YOU HAVE IT NOW**

```
case    : 
    name    : tandem solar cell
    options :
        verbose : true
        t_stamp : system
    units   :
        energy  : eV
        length  : nm
        time    : s
        tension : V
        temperature: K
        mqty    : mole
        light   : cd
    regions :
        layer   : Glass
            geometry:
                thick   : 80 nm
                npoints : 10
            optical :
                nk_file : vacuum.txt
        layer   : FTO
            geometry:
                thick   : 10 nm
                npoints : 10
            optical :
                nk_file : vacuum.txt
```

**MODIFIED DATA TO COMPLY WITH YAML SYNTAX**

```
case    : 
    name    : tandem solar cell
    options :
        verbose : true
        t_stamp : system # a sample comment
    units   :
        energy  : eV
        length  : nm
        time    : s
        tension : V
        temperature: K
        mqty    : mole
        light   : cd
    regions : 
        -   layer   : Glass # ADDED THE - TO MAKE IT A LIST OF LAYERS
            geometry :      # AND KEEP INDENTATION PROPERLY
                thick   : 80 nm
                npoints : 10
            optical :
                nk_file : vacuum.txt
        -   layer   : FTO
            geometry:
                thick   : 10 nm
                npoints : 10
            optical :
                nk_file : vacuum.txt
```

With only these instruction you get your object parsed:

```
import yaml
data = yaml.load(text)

""" your data would be parsed as:
{'case': {'name': 'tandem solar cell',
          'options': {'t_stamp': 'system', 'verbose': True},
          'regions': [{'geometry': {'npoints': 10, 'thick': '80 nm'},
                       'layer': 'Glass',
                       'optical': {'nk_file': 'vacuum.txt'}},
                      {'geometry': {'npoints': 10, 'thick': '10 nm'},
                       'layer': 'FTO',
                       'optical': {'nk_file': 'vacuum.txt'}}],
          'units': {'energy': 'eV',
                    'length': 'nm',
                    'light': 'cd',
                    'mqty': 'mole',
                    'temperature': 'K',
                    'tension': 'V',
                    'time': 's'}}}

"""
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what would be the best way to retrieve this python dict in matlab/octave though?

I couldn't find a way to convert it in a struct, but I suppose it would be enough if I can access them in a consistent way.

Comment: I don't think you have to use python at all. You should use a YAML library for Octave and parse it into the proper Octave data structures.